# Alsa cannot find capture card

Tags: alsa

I have a headless machine running Ubuntu server 16.04. I am trying to record audio and video from a Hauppauge ImpactVCB-e PCI Express video capture card. Currently I can record video, but not audio. The audio input of the capture card is listed in `/proc/asound/cards`,

```
cameron@server:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xd3000000 irq 16
 1 [CX23885        ]: CX23885 - Conexant CX23885
                      Conexant CX23885 at cx23885[0]
cameron@server:~$ ls /proc/asound/card1
id  pcm0c
```

but it is not listed when I run `arecord -l`,

```
cameron@server:~$ arecord -l
arecord: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

Looking through `dmesg` output I found the following in reference to the PCI card,

```
[    0.370573] pci 0000:60:00.0: [14f1:8852] type 00 class 0x040000
[    0.370625] pci 0000:60:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd3200000-0xd33fffff 64bit]
[    0.370739] pci 0000:60:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.370742] pci 0000:60:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot
[    0.370803] pci 0000:60:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.370862] pci 0000:60:00.0: disabling ASPM on pre-1.1 PCIe device.  You can enable it with 'pcie_aspm=force'
[    0.423205] pci_bus 0000:60: resource 1 [mem 0xd3200000-0xd33fffff]
```

I expect this is an issue with my Alsa configuration, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please edit question with output of `cat /proc/asound/cards` and `ls /proc/asound/card99`, replacing `99` with the number of the Haupauge card shown in the first command. Also, look in `dmesg` after boot for any relevant messages that describe successful initialization, or problems. If you don't know how to do that, upload the whole `dmesg` output to a pastebin etc., and edit question with link.

Comment: @dirkt, I added the details you requested to the question.

Comment: The card shows up with a capture device `pcm0c`, so I suspect the hardware drivers are ok. Funnily, you don't even get `arecord -l` devices for card 0. Guess: It's an unusual card, so there's a regression that causes an error when ALSA goes through the hw driver list, hits card 1, and sets up the device and plugin list. I'd have to google how to debug this. Do you get anything with `aplay -l`? Anything with `amixer -c0 controls` or `amixer -c1 controls`? (Exact output is not important, this is just to check if these are broken, too).

Comment: `aplay -l` produces the exact same output as `arecord -l`. Both `amixer` commands output `Invalid card number` and the `amixer` useage text.

Comment: @dirkt, is there any other information which would be helpful to you?

Comment: Ok, googled a bit. Try `LIBASOUND_DEBUG=1 aplay -l` and see if this outputs any errors. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to allow tracing. You can also `strace aplay -l`, and see if you notice anything odd (or upload output to pastebin and edit question with link). What you should see is libasound reading `alsa.conf` (more than once), and trying to open `/dev/snd/controlC*` in turn, succeeding for the cards you actually have.

Comment: @dirkt, running `strace aplay -l` I noticed one line of the output, `open("/dev/snd/controlC1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)`. Running `sudo stract aplay -l` fixed this issue and running `sudo arecord -l` shows my capture card. Looking at the contents of the `/dev/snd` directory it appears the issue was that my user was not in the `audio` group. I will work on adding myself to the `audio` group and write up an answer for this question. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I determined that the issue was that my user was not in the `audio` group. The `groups` command can be used to see the list of groups a user is in. Running `sudo arecord -l` showed my capture device. To allow access to my capture card without superuser privileges I ran `sudo usermod -a -G audio $(whoami)` and rebooted the computer.